# No indexing to all the URLs ending in feed

Tags: google, noindex

I want to add no indexing to all the URLs ending in "/feed" using an x-robots-tag. There is a code to noindex doc files

```
<FilesMatch ".doc$">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, noarchive, nosnippet"
</FilesMatch>
```

But there is no code to block feed URLs .

Comment: Have you tried replacing `.doc` with `/feed` in that rule?  Does that not work?